# Cylinder geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, cylindrical-coordinates

I want to measure the surface contour of a cylinder. I am using a laser line scanner to measure it. I am currently facing a problem with x-tilt - a misalignment caused when the measurement laser line is not parallel to the plane of rotation.

For instance, say the two points of laser line on the cylinder surface are $(x_{1},\theta_1)$ and $(x_2,\theta_2)$. If $\theta_1 = \theta_2$ then the alignment is correct. If I measure a perfectly smooth cylinder with a properly aligned sensor, z (the distance between the sensor and the cylindrical surface) as a function of x (axial length of the cylinder) would be flat line. However, if   $\theta_1 \neq \theta_2$, then z vs x would be a concave curve with peak value equal to the z_correct_aligned.

The question: How can we extract the angle by which the sensor should be rotated to ensure proper alignment when we have the curve measurement and know the radius of the cylinder?

[Attached image illustrates the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PD7Cz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laser beam when moved defines a plane. If the laser is properly aligned, the plane contains the axis of the cylinder. If it is misaligned in a way that it creates an angle with the axis, the plane it defines interescts this axis at some angle $\alpha$. Note that it is also possible to have the laser misaligned in such a way, that it defines a plane parall to the axis, but not containing it; this isn't the case you're asking about, so I won't be talking about it.

If a plane intersects the axis of a cylinder, then the crossection of the plane with the cylinder is an ellipse. It's projection on $(x,z)$ plane (which is measured) will also be an ellipse. It can be easily checked that the short axis (iun the direction $z$) of this ellipse is $R$ and the long axis (in the direction $x$) is $\frac{R}{\tan\alpha}$.

The profile you measure will be an arc of this ellipse. In a perfect situation, assuming that the maximum of the profile is at the point $(x_0,z_0)$, the profile should be given by the formula
$$ \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{R^2/\tan^2\alpha} + \frac{\big(z-(z_0-R)\big)^2}{R^2} = 1$$
that is
$$ z = z_0 + \sqrt{R^2-(x-x_0)^2\tan^2\alpha} - R$$
In a realistic situations with all possible measurement errors in the way, you don't expect full agreement with the formula, and you just need to find the value of $\alpha$ that gives the best fit. Or you can just look at $z$ around the maximum; we expect
$$ z \approx z_0 -\frac{\tan^2\alpha}{2R} (x-x_0)^2 $$
Which means that
$$ -\frac{\tan^2\alpha}{R} = z''(x_0)$$
$$ \tan^2\alpha = -R\, z''(x_0)$$
$$ \alpha = \arctan \sqrt{R\, |z''(x_0)|}$$
Fitting an ellipse to a measured profile will probably give you a better approximation for $\alpha$ than just looking at the neighbourhood of the maximum.